# chcon: failed to change context of ‘/usr/sbin/httpd’, Permission denied

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, selinux

I am new to SELiunx concept and as per the [RHEL7 > SELinux User's and Administrator's Guide > 3.2. UNCONFINED PROCESSES](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-targeted_policy-unconfined_processes)

**Audit log**

```
type=IPC msg=audit(1624375715.312:4225): ouid=0 ogid=0 mode=0666 obj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1624375715.312:4225): proctitle=2F7573722F7362696E2F6874747064002D44464F524547524F554E44
type=AVC msg=audit(1624375724.580:4226): avc:  denied  { unix_read unix_write } for  pid=25626 comm="httpd" key=1392707921  scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=shm permissive=0
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1624375724.580:4226): arch=c000003e syscall=29 success=no exit=-13 a0=53030951 a1=4338 a2=1b6 a3=6b items=0 ppid=25612 pid=25626 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

I have changed the httpd to run in `unconfind_t` domain but now I am not able to change back the httpd to `httpd_t` domain.

I made httpd to `unconfined_t` domain to make `shmget` function to work, called by one php process hosted by httpd.

```
[user@rhel7 ~]$ sudo chcon -t bin_t /usr/sbin/httpd
[user@rhel7 ~]$ ls -Z /usr/sbin/httpd
-rwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0       /usr/sbin/httpd
[user@rhel7 ~]$ systemctl start httpd.service
```

.....

```
[root@rhel7 user]# chcon -r system_r -t httpd_t /usr/sbin/httpd
chcon: failed to change context of ‘/usr/sbin/httpd’ to ‘system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0’: Permission denied
[root@rhel7 user]#
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to run `restorecon -v /usr/sbin/httpd` to restore it to the default values.

If you want to manually change it then you need to use `httpd_exec_t` as the type of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that, logged in as root, on RH 8.5, I couldn't change a file to `unconfined_t`. I realized that using `unconfined_t` isn't the right way to "fix" problems. The right way would be to either make the files part of an existing, correct type, as the user above suggested, and then use `semanage fcontext` to make that change persistent, or to define a new type and security policy. In your case, you didn't need a new policy, because `httpd_t` fits.

I was trying to change the type of a new service to `unconfined_t`. Again, ideally I should have created a whole new type and policy, but that was beyond the scope of what I could do. But:

```
chcon -t unconfined_t my_file
```

was giving permission denied.

For anyone else looking for a solution, what I did was:

```
# setenforce 0
# chcon -t unconfined_t my_file
# setenforce 1
# getenforce 
Enforcing
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to do this but it did let me get things done, and later on I'll write a new policy and figure out a type to use for it.